# How to stack centered divs vertically

Tags: html, css, css-float, center

I can't seem to figure out a way to stack my divs vertically while still aligning them in the center of the page.

This is my current html:

```css
.loading-page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.loading-page .image-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.loading-page .image-container .image-grey {
  display: block;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.loading-page .image-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0%;
  width: var(--image-load);
  height: 100%;
  background-position: top left;
}

.counter {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.counter h1 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.counter hr {
  background: #000000;
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading-page">

  <div class="image-container" style="--image-load: 50%;">
    <style>
      .image-container:after {
        background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/bZt9ZwE.png);
      }
    </style>
    <img class="image-grey" src="http://i.imgur.com/bZt9ZwE.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="counter">
    <h1>50%</h1>
    <hr/>
  </div>

</div>
```

A working example:

> [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cgLy9kt/)

The target is for the "50%" text to be below the image while both divs are centered, both vertically and horizontally. Image size is going to be dynamic thus I can't just set everything with fixed width/height and play with paddings.

Comment: Which progress bar?

Comment: "progress bar", its just an underline. Actually, I think I will erase it from the question as it serves nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `flex-direction:column;` to `.loading-page`

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
}

.loading-page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.loading-page .image-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.loading-page .image-container .image-grey {
  display: block;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.loading-page .image-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0%;
  width: var(--image-load);
  height: 100%;
  background-position: top left;
}

.counter {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.counter h1 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.counter hr {
  background: #000000;
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading-page">

  <div class="image-container" style="--image-load: 50%;">
    <style>
      .image-container:after {
        background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/bZt9ZwE.png);
      }
    </style>
    <img class="image-grey" src="http://i.imgur.com/bZt9ZwE.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="counter">
    <h1>50%</h1>
    <hr/>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go!
Tip: don't use pixels(px), they can't be responsive... instead, use percentage as a unit of measurement to make it responsive.

**EDIT:** I Updated my answer... now it's responsive. Hope it helps!

```css
    .loading-page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.loading-page .image-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.loading-page .image-container .image-grey {
  display: block;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.loading-page .image-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0%;
  width: var(--image-load);
  height: 100%;
  background-position: top left;
}

.counter {
  text-align: center;
  position: static;
  width: 200px;
}

.counter h1 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: -5%;
}

.counter hr {
  background: #000000;
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading-page">

<div class="image-container" 
   style="--image-load: 50%;">
 <style>.image-container:after { background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/bZt9ZwE.png);}</style>
 <img class="image-grey" src="http://i.imgur.com/bZt9ZwE.png"/>
</div>
<div class="counter">
  <h1>50%</h1>
<hr/>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Even though your solution is good, elaborate on what you've done to get it working. (Even though I know you added position absolute :p)

Comment: Does work for the fiddle's exact image, doesn't work if we change the size (maybe to 250x250px). The text is over the image. Or is there something I've missed in the solution?

Comment: I updated my answer... now it's responsive... You can change the size of the picture... it doenst matter :D try it out and let me know if it worked

Comment: Glad it worked :) Mark it as the valid one so we can help more people with the same problem! Cheers :)